# Font Size to Re-size Based on Window Size

Tags: html, css, fonts, resize, font-size

Is there a simple way to make a font re-size itself based on the window size?

For example, the font would look bigger on a Desktop than on a mobile device. This way, users on a smaller screen will not have the font take up all the room.

I tried using "px" "em" and "%" but none of them seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I have found to do this is to use a little trick coupled with media queries. I set the `body` element's font-size to something in `px` (some people will probably explode about the use of `px` for font sizes instead of `em`, this i just my personal preference). Say for example:

`body{ font-size: 20px; }`

i then set all other elements as a percentage of this `body` element. so if i want my `h1`s to be 30px i set them like:

`h1 { font-size: 150%;    /* (30/20) * 100 = 150 */ }`

However, it may be pertinent to have certain element be a fixed font size at all screen sizes, say for example you're using a glyph font and want to have your icons always stay a particular size for alignment purposes. In this case i would use a set `px` height again. For example:

`.icon { font-size: 15px; }`

What this means then is rather than having to change a whole lot of different element's font-sizes at different screen widths, i only have to change the `body` element in order to globally effect all `%` sized elements with no fixed `px` parents. For example:

```
@media (min-width: 992px){
    body{
        font-size:14px;
    }
}
```

You then only have 1 element you really have to worry about changing. Of course this method can be applied just as easily to `em` units if you'd prefer

Answer (score 1):

Use **Javascript** to detect the screen size and then change the size of font and friends  `@media` tag option is right but for that you must need to specify the size of screen . But in javascript you never need to this because it change the font size according to your modification code for all screen